# Как в XML-файле прописать путь от родителя к необходимому элементу php?

Tags: php, парсер, xml

Нуждаюсь в Вашей помощи =)

Есть XML-файл.
Загружаю его по ссылке так:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://example.com');
```

Для примера:

```
<shop>
    <name>Shop name</name>
    <company>Company name</company>
    <url>https://example.com/shop</url>
    <url>https://example.com/shop2</url>
    <url>https://example.com/shop3</url>
    <currencies>
        <currency>
            <name>XXX</name>
        </currency>
        <currency>
            <name>YYY</name>
        </currency>
        <currency>
            <name>ZZZ</name>
        </currency>
    </currencies>
</shop>
```

Требуется получить все имена элементов, их количество и путь от самого начала до указанного элемента.

Получаю элементы и количество таким образом:

```
$elements = [];
        foreach ($xml->xpath('//*') as $element) {
            $name = $element->getName();
            $elements[$name]['count'] = ($elements[$name]['count'] ?? 0) + 1;
            $elements[$name]['path'] = $name; // Вот тут надо что-то другое
        }
```

А вот с этим ($elements[$name]['path'] = $name;) не могу разобраться.
Как мне прописать путь от самого верхнего родителя до выбранного?
Чтобы получилось нечто подобное:

```
array:10 [▼
  "shop" => array:2 [▼
    "count" => 1
    "path" => "shop"
  ]
  "name" => array:2 [▼
    "count" => 1
    "path" => "shop.name"
  ]
  "currency" => array:2 [▼
    "count" => 3
    "path" => "shop.currencies.currency"
  ]
   ...
]
```

Хэлп ми! Хэлп ми!

Answer (score 1):

Скачивай фал и далее по списку:

$path = "maxi.xml";

$xmlfile = file_get_contents($path);

$new = simplexml_load_string($xmlfile);

$con = json_encode($new);

$newArr = json_decode($con, true);

simplexml_load_file - зло, ты так себе накачаешь хз шо